# Xtext - Generating object - generate more data

Tags: eclipse-emf, xtext, generated-code, xtend

I have xtext file similar to the xtext describe in here:
(www.ebpml.org/blog2/index.php/2010/11/05/mde-xtext-and-json)

```
JSONDataSource: root = Object ;
Object: '{' firstObject=TerminalObject (',' objects+=TerminalObject)* '}';
Array: '['firstItem=ObjectValue (',' items+=ObjectValue)* ']';
EmptyObject: isEmpty?= '{}' ;
EmptyArray: isEmpty?= '[]' ;
ObjectValue: value=STRING | Object | Array | EmptyObject | EmptyArray ;
TerminalObject: element=STRING ':' (content = ObjectValue) ;
```

So after generating the code I have all the objects generated in java.
now in I want to have more methods in those generated java files.

what is the best way to do so?
thanks :)

Comment: Please elaborate what do you mean by having methods in the generated java files? Did you write a generator based on these values? Or do you want to write a method inside the datasource file?

Comment: the generated code for the above xtext file are the classes JSONDataSource, Object, Array, EmptyObject, EmptyArray, ObjectValue, TerminalObject as interfaces and also are being generated the impl classes of the above.

for example the generated class of is attached

Comment: public class ArrayImpl extends ObjectValueImpl implements Array
{
  protected ObjectValue firstItem;
  protected EList<ObjectValue> items;
  protected ArrayImpl() 
  {super();}
  @Override
  protected EClass eStaticClass() 
  { return JsonPackage.Literals.ARRAY;}
  public ObjectValue getFirstItem()
  { return firstItem;}
  public NotificationChain basicSetFirstItem(ObjectValue newFirstItem, NotificationChain msgs)
  {..}
  public void setFirstItem(ObjectValue newFirstItem)
  {..}
  public EList<ObjectValue> getItems()
  {..}

Comment: public EList<ObjectValue> getItems()
  {..}
  @ Override
  public NotificationChain eInverseRemove(InternalEObject otherEnd, int featureID, NotificationChain msgs)
  {..}
  @ Override
  public Object eGet(int featureID, boolean resolve, boolean coreType)
  {..}
  @ SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @ Override
  public void eSet(int featureID, Object newValue)
  {..}
  @ Override
  public void eUnset(int featureID)
  {..}
  @ Override
  public boolean eIsSet(int featureID)
  {..}
} //ArrayImpl

Comment: how can i upload the file to the conversation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are no easy ways to customize these classes. You can do basically two things:

1. Create your own EMF (Ecore) model, and create your grammar in a way that reuses your Ecore model. This way, you can define new operations, and create their implementations manually.
2. You could also set up a postprocessor for the Ecore model generator that fills out the contents. See http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/customizing-xtext-metamodel-inference-using-xtend2/ for details - but be vary, as the model inference cannot directly output custom code; there are some EMF genmodel-annotation based way to create the bodies of generated code (see the final part of http://jevopisdeveloperblog.blogspot.hu/2011/03/implement-tostring-with-xtexts.html for details).

Alltogether, customizing the generated EMF models is quite hard, and I do not recommend doing it. Although it seems unnecessary to introduce new helper classes, technologically it is much easier to do.

Comment: Hi,
I have another Q regarding that.
So now I can generate code successfully! but I want to call a static method in another scope, How can I add import to the relevant package?

Comment: If you are using the first way, you simply edit your EObject implementations. If you are using the second way, I know of no possible way to do it. However, you can use fully qualified names as a workaround.

Comment: If I'm using the second way can i add a new field to generated class?

Comment: Yes. Add a new EAttribute to the EClass#eAttributes while editing it (or EReference to the EClass#eStructuralFeatures, if you want to add a reference to another EObject).

Comment: If the answer was useful, you might consider marking it as a correct answer.